# Add minutes to time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add minutes to my current time. Here is my code. Thank you

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let currentTime = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar.current.date(byAdding:,value:,to:)` method.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let currentTime = formatter.string(from: Date())
let tenMinutesLater = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 10, to: Date())!
print(formatter.string(from: tenMinutesLater))
```

Or simply:

```
print(formatter.string(from: Date().addingTimeInterval(10*60)))
```

Comment: You need to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the dateFormat.

Answer (score -1):

Try this extension:

```
 extension Date {
     
    public func addMinute(_ minute: Int) -> Date? {
        var comps = DateComponents()
        comps.minute = minute
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let result = calendar.date(byAdding: comps, to: self)
        return result ?? nil
    }

 }
```

Usage: Example I add 10 minutes.

```
 let originalDate: Date = Date()
 let newDate = originalDate.addMinute(10)
```